# How to have multiple App-Hooks on a Django CMS Page?

Tags: django, django-cms

Is it possible to have multiple App-Hooks attached to a single CMS page?

From the interface it seems that I can only add one per page.

Comment: I don't think you can. You could write a wrapper app-hook that includes the two separates apps via the urls

Comment: You can't. What are you needing to accomplish?

Comment: Hmm ok I was just wondering if it as possible since I wanted a nice way to handle Ajax requests and form submits from 2 separate apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have more than on Apphook on a single page.

The reason for that is how Apphooks work. If an Apphook is attached to a page, the responsibility of rendering that page (and child pages) is delegated from the CMS to that app. Hooking two apps would result in the CMS to be unable to figure out which app needs to handle  the requests.

The solution would be to write an Apphook that combines the urlpatterns (and optionally menus) of the two existing Apphooks and exposes them as a single Apphook to the CMS.